# How to use express response to stay in the same page without redirect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, response

Consider a simple form which takes email as input. Submit button calls a bootstrap modal in case authentication failed. If at success, it redirects to the next view.

When bootstrap modal appears, the browser is constantly loading the page, waiting a response.

I am using this code on server side:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    Users.findOne({
        email: req.body.email
    })
    .then(user => {
        if (user) {
            obj = req.body.email
            res.redirect('/survey')
        }
    })
})
```

I tried to add an `else` statement in case user is not found:

```
...
else  {
  console.log('User not found')
  return
}
```

I do not want to redirect to the same page because modal will not work.

Is there a `res` method in order to achieve this?

Comment: did you try to add `return` before `res.redirect('/survey')`  so it becomes `return res.redirect('/survey');`?

Comment: It redirects ok, the problem is when user is not found. I mean, the second option (i.e. `else`) also works ok, but browsers is constantly loading like wainting for a response...

Comment: Well, in the else, do render the same page you are in. The browser will keep waiting until you issue a response which you don't in case user not found

Comment: but for user experience, is there an option to issue a response without redirect? Thanks, @Tareq

Answer (score 1):

**The proper solution will be to use ajax for submitting form data & handling response**

**based on the response success / failure, you can redirect user or show modal for error from client side**

If you still want to do it without ajax submission of form, you can redirect user to same url with adding querystring

```
res.redirect('/same-path?error=user_not_found')
```

And check query params on load of page in client javascript

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
    var url = window.location.search;
    var queryStr = url.split("?")[1];

    if(queryStr) {
        let hash = queryStr.split('&);
        for (var i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
            params=hash[i].split("=");
            if(params[0] == 'error' && params[1] == 'user_not_found') {
                // SHOW YOUR MODAL HERE
            }
        }
    }
});​
```